# Accessing Database created in one activity from another activity

Tags: android, android-context, sqliteopenhelper, android-database, android-application-class

I have created an instance of my database helper class in the main activity.

I want to access that instance from any another activity where I can update that database. 
I have created an instance with `getApplicationContext()` as `context` but it's still not showing that instance in another activity.

Comment: create a static instance.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Main Activity, you can create database on Application file.

Then you can access it from anywhere, not specific activity.

Application App

```
public class ApplicantApp extends Application{

    private static Database yourdatabasevariable;
}
```

Another Activity

```
public class ActivityA{
   Application.yourdatabasevariable;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the same and it works.